# How do I change the favicon.ico from the spring leaf to my own figure?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application in which I want to replace my favicon with Boot's default favicon i.e.the green leaf.

To resolve the problem, I have tried the following:

1. Externally create `FaviconConfiguration` class
2. Set property `spring​.​mvc​.​favicon​.​enabled` to false

Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20681956/1157121

In short words, try to place your favicon in the static content directory is the easiest way.